# Replacing texture pixels with bitmaps that contain alpha (function texSubImage2D)

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I am using a GLES20 texture in my app, which I am loading with `texImage2D` function. Sometimes I have to modify small area of the loaded texture with bitmap that I create on the fly. Bitmap contains transparency (some pixels have alpha < 255). When I call function `texSubImage2D` the pixels with alpha values < 255 get replaced with black pixels.

My code (I have removed non-relevant parts) looks like this:

```
// Set blending function
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// Create bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(20, 20, Config.ARGB_8888);

// Draw on the bitmap
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmp);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paint.setColor(Color.argb(100, 255, 0, 0));
c.drawRect(0, 0, 20, 20, paint);

// Bind to the texture I want to modify
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

// Draw on the texture
GLUtils.texSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, myX, myY, bitmap);

// Free memory
bitmap.recycle();
```

If I use 255 alpha (change `paint.setColor(Color.argb(100, 255, 0, 0));` to `paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));`) then everything is OK, but alpha is lost of course.

How can I draw a bitmap with transparent pixels on the GLES20 texture without loosing the transparency?

Comment: Check out custom implementation of glTexSubImage2D used in AndEngine located here: http://bit.ly/15CGQ4v . I think this might help you.

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out. Do you know by any chance, will that merge the existing pixels on the texture with the new ones (for example, if the original texture has all white pixels, and I will draw a rectangle with color RGBA(255, 0, 0, 100), will I end up with pink rectangle) or it will replace the pixels all-together, so the texture area which I will replace will have RGBA(255, 0, 0, 100) value (which is dark red if texture is drawn on black background)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know this. But I guess this will simply replace the pixels, which is probably not what you wanted. Maybe you should try with framebuffer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try and let you know. If it doesn't work, I'll try rendering on the texture: http://blog.shayanjaved.com/2011/05/13/android-opengl-es-2-0-render-to-texture/

It also sounds promissing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to:

- Keep a copy of the whole texture around as a `Bitmap` and draw onto that using whatever [mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) you want.
- [Make a copy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) of the section of the bitmap that you changed (or update an existing bitmap to avoid allocating memory each time).
- Upload that smaller bitmap using [glTexSubImage2D](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLUtils.html#texSubImage2D%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) with the appropriate x and y `offset`.

The reason that you will have to copy into a smaller bitmap is that `glTexSubImage2D` doesn't support uploading a section (rectangle) of a bitmap. It does however allow you to update a section of the texture using the `offset` parameters.